# Cognos report number formatting into 1 decimal form

Tags: reporting, number-formatting, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have two different reports in Cognos.
Whereas in both the reports I have the field called "%Target".
In the report 1 the field is directly coming from db and in the report 2 the field is formulated.
My question is for e.g. if a value is 98.47% (directly coming from db) in report 1 where after applying formatting it give me the rounded value as 98.5% but however in report 2 (where the field is calculated e.g. A/B) this value is populated as 98.4%
Can anyone please explain why this happening.
However I tried using ceiling function. But nothing is working on the report.

Comment: Can you provide the two numbers you are dividing to get .9847? Are you applying a percentage data format in the report to convert it to a percentage? I tried to replicate and could not.

Comment: Hi Johnsonium 2, yes I m using percentage format for the field by defining number of decimal place 1.And also I will get the two dividing numbers and revert back to you.